# Cannot Resolve Set-Cookie header issue even though i have set sameSit: none and secure :true

Tags: cookies, deployment, passport.js, samesite

I have this fullstack application which uses passport authentication. When i used it in localhost both front end and backend worked fine. I then deployed my frontend on vercel and backend on railways. I set up the cors to accept the cross origins. Also then i set cookie headers to sameSite: none and secure:true.
Interestingly if i don't do this "sameSite: none and secure:true", my backend was working fine.

So like when i call post login request from backend it was saving cookie (when this options were disabled or default values), this time my front end was not storing  "Cookie header or Set-cookie header", infact it was giving me this warning---- This Set-Cookie didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was default to "SameSite=Lax" in the response headers.

Next when i added these options to my cookie. Even my backend stopped storing that cookies.
I have connections on https

following are codes that i think might explain what i mean.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq1kF.png)

these are the passport login routes
[do i need to set cookie on each response?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsMhf.png)

My cookie object
[this is after adding those options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqRJP.png)

after adding those options i cannot see any cookie even when i call from backend
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezWSg.png)

also for some reason even when my backend code was storing cookies when i made request from frontend not even did it store cookie but also passport was giving req.user as undefined,(i guess because no cookie was accessible?)

```
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("../models/User");
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log(user, "from the serialize user");
  console.log("mein serialised mein hu");
  done(null, user._id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(async (userId, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    console.log(user, "from the Deserialize user");
    done(null, user); //here req.user will store user.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    done(err);
  }
});
```